# How to calculate ages in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two databases in the same server(dbA and dbB). The both have a table called CUSTOMERS. I want to calculate the age of my customers and instert it on a column AGE, on the dbB.CUSTOMERS, based on the current date and the DateOfBirth column on the dbA.CUSTOMERS table.

To calculate the age I tried to use

```
SELECT floor(months_between(SYSDATE, (SELECT BIRTH_DATE FROM dbA.CUSTOMERS)) /12) from dual;
```

but this returns an `ORA-01427:single-row subquery returns more than one row`

I am guessing this is because the subquery returns every row of the BIRTH_DATE column. Is there someway to do this for all the rows and then insert the result to my dbB.CUSTOMERS table?

I am using OracleSQL

Comment: Why?  Age changes over time.  You'd be better off building and calling a function when needed.  If it was deterministic you could use a function based index; but this isn't deterministic, so again why?  Seems to me a function would be of better use here.

Comment: @xQbert This is for an exercise so the age changing over time is irrelevant.

Comment: Very poorly chosen exercise. Whatever the instructor is trying to demonstrate (or test), they should choose better examples, that resemble what one would actually do in the real world. This assignment would be pretty idiotic in the real world, and it would be very easy to come up with a meaningful assignment that demonstrates exactly the same features, techniques etc. without suggesting or implying that storing ages in a table somehow makes sense. Just my 2 cents...

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for the subquery here

```
select floor(months_between(sysdate,BIRTH_DATE)/12) as Age
from CUSTOMERS
```

Using the subquery returns all the rows for the table and cannot apply the functions against all of them. This method applies the function against each row, so it works

Comment: Wow it was that simple. I thought I needed the subquery to grab the column from the other DB. Thank you.